# Keepalived exit with status 2

Tags: bash, high-availability, keepalived

Hello I am having problem with my keepalived.

on the logs it's said that check script is exiting with status 2 while

Here is the log

```
Nov 11 19:54:03 MCX-G2 Keepalived_vrrp[15201]: VRRP_Script(chk_server) failed (exited with status 2)
Nov 11 19:54:03 MCX-G2 Keepalived_vrrp[15201]: VRRP_Script(chk_script) succeeded
Nov 11 19:54:03 MCX-G2 Keepalived_vrrp[15201]: (VRRP1) Entering BACKUP STATE
```

Below is the part of keepalived config

```
  vrrp_script chk_server {
  script       "/bin/ping -c 1 100.100.100.1 &> /dev/null"
  interval 10   # check every 10 seconds
  fall 1       # require 1 failures for KO
  rise 1       # require 1 successes for OK
}
```

while ping is success :

```
root@MCX-G2 /bin # /bin/ping -c 1 172.20.128.100
PING 172.20.128.100 (172.20.128.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.20.128.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.319 ms

--- 172.20.128.100 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.319/0.319/0.319/0.000 ms
root@MCX-G2 /bin #
```

I don't see any suspicious mis-config or something like that.
Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: If you have a problem with keeping your post around, please flag it rather than editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the keepalived.conf manual page, it looks for `a script to be executed periodically`.

```
VRRP script(s)
        # Adds a script to be executed periodically. Its exit code will be
        # recorded for all VRRP instances which are monitoring it.
        vrrp_script <SCRIPT_NAME> {
           script <STRING>|<QUOTED-STRING> # path of the script to execute
```

So this should solve the issue:

- adding your command to a script file like `script.sh`.

  - `cat /script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null
```

- Make the script file executable by running:

  - `chmod +x /script.sh`
- and use the following value for the `script` parameter in your keepalive configuration file.

`script "/script.sh"`

Comment: Don't forget to enable execution privileges for SELINUX: `chcon -t keepalived_unconfined_script_exec_t /chk_nebula.sh`